# Unable to update class variable after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, class

After getting two integer upon the ajax request has been completed, `this.N` and `this.M` are not getting set by `storeDims()` even if the `dims` has correctly been decoded. So it seems that I cannot acces `this.N` and `this.M` declared in the constructor.
This is the code

```
class MapModel {

    constructor() {
        this.N; // need to initialize this after an ajax call
        this.M;
        this.seats = new Array();
        this.remote_seats = new Array();
    }

    init(callback) {
        let _this = this;
        $.when(
            _this.getDims(),
            _this.getSeats(),
        ).then(this.initMap(callback))
    }


    initMap(callback) {
        console.log(this.N); // prints undefined
        console.log(this.M); // this as well
        callback(this.N, this.M, this.seats);
    }

    getDims() {
        let _this = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'src/php/data.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {action: 'getDims'},
            success: function (result) {
                let dims = JSON.parse(result); // dims[0] = 10, dims[1] = 6
                _this.storeDims(dims);
            }
        });
    }

    storeDims(dims) {
        console.log(dims);
        this.N = parseInt(dims[0]);
        this.M = parseInt(dims[1]);
        console.log(this.N);
        console.log(this.M);
    }

    getSeats() {
    let _this = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'src/php/data.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {action: 'getSeats'},
        success: function (result) {
            let seats = JSON.parse(result);
            _this.storeSeats(seats);
        }
    });
}

storeSeats(seats) {
    this.remote_seats = seats;
    console.log(this.remote_seats);
}
}
```

Comment: do you have the log `console.log(dims);` in your console?

Comment: @madalinivascu yes it is: `(2) […]
​
0: 10
​
1: 6
​
length: 2
​
<prototype>: Array []
`

Comment: see my answer bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the ajax promises from the `getDms` and `getSeats` functions

```
 getDims() {
        let _this = this;
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'src/php/data.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {action: 'getDims'},
            success: function (result) {
                let dims = JSON.parse(result); // dims[0] = 10, dims[1] = 6
                _this.storeDims(dims);
            }
        });
    }
```

you can even pass the values directly to the initMap

```
init(callback) {
        let _this = this;
        $.when(
          _this.getDims(),
          _this.getSeats()
        ).then(function(dims,seats) {_this.initMap(dims,seats,callback)})
    }


    initMap(dimsRaw,seatsRaw, callback) {
        let dims = JSON.parse(dimsRaw);
        console.log(dims[0]); 
        console.log(dims[1]); 
        callback(dims[0], dims[1], this.seats);
    }
```

Comment: I've updated my code above, now I need to get two arrays and after that call the `initMap` function

Comment: updated my answer, the second params of the then callback is the seats, for more info see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: why `storeDims` and `storeSeats` won't update the `this.` variable declared inside the constructor? I was expecting the `initMap` to work with those variables after that the ajax call initialize them.

Answer (score 0):

The `init` promise callback is being called on the chain declaration, try adding a function wrapper:

```js
    init(callback) {
        let _this = this;
        $.when(
            _this.getDims(),
        ).then(function() {_this.initMap(callback)})
    }
```